# Android current year and month in spinner

Tags: android, date, spinner

with this code I view the current year in spinner, now I want to also see the current month. how? thanks

```
    if (years.size() == 0){
        int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int currentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        years.add(currentYear+"/"+currentMonth);
    }

    SpinnerAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, years);

    yearSelector.setAdapter(adapter);
    yearSelector.setSelection(0);
    yearSelector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String anno = years.get(position);

            showDetails(anno);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: can you put your spinner codes ?

Comment: To get month from calendar object, simple call `calendar.get(Calendar.Month)`

Comment: I have included the complete code of the spinner

Answer (score 2):

You can get current month by

```
int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
int currentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
years.add(currentYear+"/"+currentMonth);
```

As month is zero based in android so you have to add 1 to get current month

Comment: You want to show both current date and current month on spinner?

Comment: Try my updated code.It will display both year and month on the spinner

Comment: I added your code but the start of Activity spinner is positioned to January
See my complete code.
thanks

Comment: to obtain the data for the current year and the current month I'm using this query.
the spinner I have to display the year and the month.

private List<String> ottieniAnni(){

...

String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y-%m',"+GiornateTable.DATA+") FROM "+GiornateTable.TABLE_NAME;
...

Comment: You want to display current yr and month on spinner and on setOnItemSelectedListener you want to show details corresponding to the current yr and month.Your spinner will only have one item in it ie. current yr and month.Is this you want?I am not actually getting your problem.

Comment: sorry maybe I have not explained well. The code works well. Activity-opening but the spinner does not display the current month but is positioned over January (01) should now position itself instead of september (09).

Comment: Check your date on device which you are testing.Is it set to todays date or set to some date in January 2013?